# Loading Images from String In Android

Tags: java, android

I have image in the as a string and it is in the form:

```
�����JFIF���������C�



%# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(���C



(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((�����"��������������������������������������N���H3�ӗ�2g�?^Ia���a�$��tsE�����
���u]y�ڻ�a�X�B��Xah����v
èV^z@�)t����
��u��THf�   !�$���X$���$`!�VZUe V$0��#���HL�ue�y   $I$� �)$),�տE9v�Í�V��벿G�n�!@*�*�h�tz�oO�oB�n�z��q�n�"k��v�=�����y��������ߐ<�tp�����H@�[V� ���d��YQ��+Hzk��$���eɳ'Lb��{p��$�&���mVƛ鿗{�8�U�O^y벿G�H.`1V���rz�|���6Q��m|{�o:�u���y��u��&.�=�cU�vu疭���5W����!����BA]Vר��V2�FH�H@@�Yh��!����bd$V\��u�*n��$HA���6B -��E��ǽ�&7]7S۞z�;�H��l���^֌�>wұ��s�o�]�崽1Xj�5����(���6~�9o7M�l�u���Sn��{���9>��.pd��@V��ʵ�ej���C%B����+zk+��!�!"����מ*n��$�BCY$)!�m��Ѣ�{����;r�]���!/G������x����&Ʈ���W]��-��e��V�_�����lH!s�Q�e�b:y�cD�י����+J#�aUUmz�l�t|�$�"@%���ebIMmv0��H��\{1�犫+��h���
```

my question is how should I load this into ImageView? I have tried converting into byte array and then into bitmap and loading it but nothing has worked

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. "nothing has worked" isn't a problem description anyone could help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't hold an image as a string like that-  with unicode and different text encodings you're asking for problems.  If you absolutely HAVE to do it (and it should be avoided if at all possible), it should be encoded as Byte64, not used as raw bytes.  You would then decode that into a byte array, the byte array into a bitmap, and the bitmap into a bitmap drawable for the image view.